# Example of $k[x]$-module where $k$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to understand what a $k[x]$-module is by cooking up an example.

Let $k = \mathbb R$. Then, our ring is $\mathbb R[x]$, so elements look like $2 + 3x$ or $3 + 5x^2 + 9x^6$. Let the group in question be $\mathbb R^3$. According to page 17 of Atiyah and Macdonald in *Commutative Algebra*, our $\mathbb R[x]$-module could then be the pair $(\mathbb R^3, \times)$ so that the following example calculations are valid:

- $ (2 + 3x) (\mathbf y + \mathbf z) = (2 + 3x) (\mathbf y) + (2 + 3x) (\mathbf z) $
- $ [(2 + 3x) + (3 + 5x^2 + 9x^6)] \mathbf y = [5 + 3x + 5x^2 + 9x^6] \mathbf y $
- $ [(2) \times (x + 4x^2)] \mathbf y = [2x + 8x^2] \mathbf y $
- $ 1 \mathbf y = \mathbf y $

Is this correct?

---

I also want to use the following definition to understand our $\mathbb R[x]$-module:

> [An equivalent definition of an $\mathbb R [x]$-module is:] $\mathbb R^3$ is an abelian group together with a ring homomorphism $\mathbb R [x] \to \operatorname{End} (\mathbb R^3)$.

What, concretely, is this ring homomorphism and in what way is it "together" with the group $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Pick a linear map $L:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$. For $v\in\mathbb R^3$, first define $x\cdot v:=L(v)$, and, more generally, for a polynomial $p\in\mathbb R[x]$, $p=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ define $p\cdot v:=p(L)(v)$, i.e. $p\cdot v:=a_0v+a_1L(v)+\ldots+a_nL^n(v)$. Does this help?

Comment: (Now recall that another name for “a linear map of $\mathbb R^3$ to itself” is “an endomorphism of $\mathbb R^3$”, and that the map $p\mapsto p(L)$ is a homomorphism of the ring $\mathbb R[x]$ to the ring of all linear maps of $\mathbb R^3$ to itself.)

Comment: A module over $k[X]$ is precisely a $k$-vector space along with an endomorphism.

Comment: @StinkingBishop It is helpful, but I'm confused about the details: is the first part of my question correct? I can't think of an $L$ that would give the same result. For example $L : \mathbf v \mapsto \mathbf v$ would give $p \cdot \mathbf v = (a_0 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n) \mathbf v$. Is the unknown variable $x$ in $\mathbb R [x]$ "supposed to" disappear?

Comment: The "unknown variable" acts as your chosen linear map. If your linear map is the identity, then indeed your formula is right. But you can choose any linear map, which will give you a corresponding module structure on the same vector space $\mathbb R^3$.